# Can the Senate put an in-progress impeachment trial on pause?

Tags: united-states, impeachment, senate-rules

## Background

Mitch McConnell has [released a statement](https://www.republicanleader.senate.gov/newsroom/press-releases/mcconnell-statement-on-senate-schedule-jan-2021) stating that the impeachment trial will not begin until the next regular meeting following the receipt from the house:

> The House of Representatives has voted to impeach the President. The Senate process will now begin at our first regular meeting following receipt of the article from the House.

This likely means that, barring an extremely quick trial, this will go on into Biden's presidency.  A concern that [Biden himself](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/533753-trump-impeachment-collides-with-bidens-agenda) has raised is that the impeachment trial will cut into the beginning of his presidency, as he states:

> “Can we go half day on dealing with impeachment, and half day getting my people nominated and confirmed in the Senate as well as moving on the package?” Biden asked. “I haven’t gotten an answer from the parliamentarian yet.”

Biden already states one proposed method to deal with this conundrum:  splitting business concurrently with typical senate processes alongside an impeachment trial. However, given that the senate will have to pause to swear in new members, elect a new Senate Majority Leader, and swear in new Senators, the Senate will have to take up non-impeachment related motions anyway.  This reality is what prompted me to ask

## Question

Can the Senate just pause an impeachment trial mid-trial entirely, then pick it up at a separate date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Parliamentarian of the United States Senate](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/RS20544.pdf) is the official advisor to the Senate on the interpretation of Standing Rules and parliamentary procedure and both Biden and McConnell have said she will need to answer that question.

Senate procedures can be changed however, given enough Senators in favour! In addition the US Constitution states "[the Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments](https://www.senate.gov/civics/constitution_item/constitution.htm#a1_sec2)" so whatever they decide it it unlikely to be open to challenge from outside the Senate.